# Custom repositories for chocolatey

Tags: windows, package-management, chocolatey

I see a lot of web posts about custom repos ("sources" in choco terminology) available for chocolatey. e.g. windowsfeatures and webpi. However, none of the commands work on choco 0.9.9  (e.g. choco install iis -source webpi) because those custom sources are not pre-installed.

Choco wiki mentions these commands and examples but points to a newer wiki (supposedly after upgrade from 0.9.8 to 0.9.9). does it mean that after 0.9.9 they removed all "custom" things from the tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminology - there are custom sources which are still nupkg sources (meaning not chocolatey.org, like myget, proget, fileshare, nuget.server, etc) and then there are special alternative sources (like webpi and windowsfeatures). The two do not mean the same thing.

Choco 0.9.9 was a complete rewrite - waiting to finish alternative sources was going to be a significant impact on releasing, and we wanted to get something in folks hands that they could start using, so we decided alternative sources would be back in the 0.9.10 series. This is [issue 14](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/14). We've mentioned this in our newsletter and in the [ChangeLog](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md%23099-march-3-2015) (see known issues).

The code is finished but 0.9.10 is waiting on another major feature before we can start talking release dates.

Comment: No worries - it's hard to get the word out to everyone! :)